# Unable to access admin

Tags: path-aliases

I am trying to access the admin of my Drupal site but .../admin and .../user are not working.
When I try to access those pages I get the 404 page.
I believe this may have been redirected similar to https://www.drupal.org/project/rename_admin_paths.

I have access to the database and files where would this configuration change be stored?

Answer (score 1):

Please specify the drupal version you  are using and is there any problem with non admin pages.

Also ensure the following:

- Include .htaccess files
- Enable clean urls
- Clear caches

Answer (score 1):

You have installed rename_admin_paths module.

[image]

Above image is the configuration page of rename_admin_paths.

Once you save this page. You admin and user url is changed. So you are getting 404 error.

You need to go to any link through admin menu. Then you can check the url and see the replacement of "admin".

Now from module list you can not go configure because it will go previous link. Let me know if you faced difficulty.

Answer (score 0):

When everything else failse, you can use the non-clean URLs:
?q=user to login, ?q=admin/...

Answer (score 0):

I was using Drupal 7.3

I finally found what I was after, we have a reverse proxy server and I looked into the configuration and found the correct address which was overriding the publicly available one.

I used that address and added */user* on the end and it worked.